# Does EarlyStopping in Keras save the best model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

When using something like:

```
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(patience=15, monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, mode='min'),
    ModelCheckpoint('best-weights.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
]

model.fit(..., callbacks=callbacks)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

am I doing the prediction with the best weights calculated during training or `model` is using the last weights (which may not be the best ones)?

So, is the above a safe approach or should I load `best-weights.h5` into the model even if the predictions are done right after training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EarlyStopping callback doesn't save anything on its own (you can double check it looking at its source code https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L458). Thus your code saves the last model that achieved the best result on dev set before the training was stopped by the early stopping callback.
I would say that, if you are saving only the best model according to dev, it is not useful to have also an early stopping callback (unless you don't want to save time and your are sure enough you are not going to find any better model if you continue the training)

Answer (score 15):

After the training stops by `EarlyStopping` callback, the current model may not be the best model with the highest/lowest monitored quantity. As a result a new argument, `restore_best_weights`, has been introduced in [Keras 2.2.3](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/releases/tag/2.2.3) release for [`EarlyStopping`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) callback if you would like to restore the best weights:

> **restore_best_weights:** whether to restore model weights from the epoch with the best value of the monitored quantity. If `False`, the
>   model weights obtained at the last step of training are used.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `model` uses the latest weights, but I could not find any evidence in the docs. 
Fortunately you can check the behavior of `model` by yourself.

First you run:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

After that, you can load `best-weights.h5` and run the prediction on the same test set again.

If `model` contains the latest weights, you should get an improved result when loading `best-weights.h5`. If the results are the same, you can be sure that model automatically uses the best achieved results.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You were both right. `model` is keeping the last weights, no matter the `EarlyStopping` callback. So best thing to do is to load the weights saved with `ModelCheckpoint`.

Comment: Correct. Always load the weights saved to the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Always load the weights saved to the disk. In this case, `best-weights.h5` on validation loss.